# Problem in fetching data using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

There is a table in database of ContactInfo class. now i want to find the value where **customerId = id**  and  **isDeleted = false**

```
 private EntityManager entityManager;
 public ContactInfo findById(long id) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ContactInfo> criteria = builder.createQuery( ContactInfo.class );
    Root<ContactInfo> root = criteria.from(ContactInfo.class);
    criteria.select(root).where(
            builder.equal(root.get("customerId"), id),
            builder.equal(root.get("isDeleted"), false)
    );
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
}
```

Contact info class:

```
public class ContactInfo extends BaseInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long cntId;
    @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT",length=4000)
    private String data;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private PersonalInfo customer;

    public ContactInfo(){ }
    public ContactInfo(Long id) {
        this.cntId = id;
    }
}
```

PersonalInfo class:

```
public class PersonalInfo extends BaseInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long customerId;//
    private Long cardId;//
}
```

BaseInfo class:

```
abstract public class BaseInfo {

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date modifiedDate;
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifiedBy;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false", nullable = false)
    private boolean isDeleted;
}
```

How to bypass the following error. thanks in advance.
**Error**

```
2018-10-07 10:47:11.742 ERROR 1168 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [customerId] on this ManagedType [com.exm.base.BaseInfo]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [customerId] on this ManagedType [com.csinfotechbd.base.BaseInfo]] with root cause
```

Comment: Please add your entity class **ContactInfo** in your question.

Comment: Please show us the code for `ContactInfo` class.

Comment: i have added all necessary classes..  plz have a look.

Comment: **customerId** is not part of ContactInfo but it is part of PersonalInfo class, so you should get customerId from PersonalInfo  class only.

Comment: i am in learning phase. i have a little knowledge about these stuff. will u plz explain me how to get out of it or any resource that will help me with this problem.

Comment: You can browse google or try the https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm

Comment: thanks.. but got nothing related from there..

Comment: Basically first you need to get **customer** from root and they try to get customerId from that element.

Comment: Do you have this project on github ?

Comment: i don't have it on github.

Comment: can u suggest some similar type of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your **customerId** is present into **PersonalInfo** entity, so your criteria query should be like below.

```
criteria.select(root).where(
    builder.equal(root.get("customer").get("customerId"), id)
);
```

Please try this.

I hope this will solve your problem.